# how to add formatting to output statement in C

Tags: c

My code works fully but for full credit we need to include a comma after every number except the last one. I'm not sure where I should place it seeing as where ever it ends up either in the for loop or out, it does not produce the correct look.

My code produces 25 0 33 like it should be needs to look like 25, 0, 33

Sample inputs: 5 25 51 0 200 33
0 50

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   
   int numVals;
   int max, min;
   
   printf("How many integers to enter?\n");
   scanf("%d", &numVals);
   
   int array[numVals];
   
   printf("Please enter %d integers: \n", numVals);
   
   for (int i = 0; i < numVals; ++i) {
      scanf("%d", &array[i]);
   }
   
   printf("Lower and upper bounds: \n");
   scanf("%d %d", max, min);
   
   for (i = 0; i < numVals; ++i) {
      if (array[i] >= min && arr[i] <= max {
         printf("%d", array[i]);
      }
   }
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your loop, can you determine if you're on the last iteration? If you can, then only print a trailing `"., "` if that's _not_ true.

Comment: It's easier to determine whether you're on the *first* iteration, and then only print a *leading* comma if that's not true.

Comment: Your other alternative is `printf (i>0?", %d":"%d", array[i]);` By setting the `i>0` condition, branch prediction will minimize the impact of the conditional only taking the `false` path of the ternary on the first iteration.

Answer (score 6):

A simple way is to change the separator after the first number.

```
 const char *sep = "";
 for (i = 0; i < numVals; ++i) {
    if (array[i] >= min && arr[i] <= max) {
       printf("%s%d", sep, array[i]);
       sep = ", ";
    }
 }
 prinf("\n");
```